# Uploading pictures to tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, tinymce

I'm writing this webpage using technologies like AngularJS, NodeJS, mongoose, mongoDB etc.
In this webpage I have a tinyMCE text-editor. Now I'm finding it nescesary for this editor to be able to have images in it. I've read about IMCE and iBrowser and the former only seems to work in Drupal, and the latter I've so far been unable to install because I have no idea what they're referring to when they say "tinyMCE init code".

My question is: Is there a better way to upload pictures to tinyMCE? Or what is the "tincMCE init code" referred to in this guide: http://netwizards.co.uk/installing-ibrowser-in-tinymce/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "tinyMCE init code" is the code in which tinyMCE gets initialized, i.e. where what plugins to be used are set, editor properties etc. See this link for more:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation

When it comes to uploading pictures in to the editor itself the tinyMCE website explains:

```
How can I upload image files from my local computer?

Short answer: You can't!

Long answer: TinyMCE is just an editor to output (X)HTML code. It is by no means     
comparable to web editing desktop software such as Adobe Dreamweaver, Go Live! or     
Microsoft Web Expressions and the like. It runs on a user's browser (client-side) and     
not on a server. If you want to upload pictures to a server then you need a server-side  
component to process your image files. TinyMCE can't do that on its own since it doesn't 
run on the server but on the user's browser.
```

You could give Froala WYSIWYG a try:
http://editor.froala.com/

Also, here is another question from stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438043/need-a-simple-wysiwyg-editor-with-image-upload

Good luck